# I am unable to recreate my angular app after I deleted it on my dashboard

Tags: angular, heroku

I deleted my app from the dashboard and now I am getting the following when I try to recreate it.

```
  /Users/denisputnam/git/invoice-dapp>heroku create
Creating app... ⣾
(node:31528) [ENOENT] Error Plugin: heroku: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/denisputnam/.config/heroku/config.json' -> '/Users/denisputnam/.local/share/heroku/config.json'
module: @oclif/config@1.13.2
task: runHook prerun
plugin: heroku
root: /usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.42.5/libexec
Creating app... done, ⬢ nameless-journey-21643
https://nameless-journey-21643.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/nameless-journey-21643.git
(base) iMac.fios-router.home:denisputnam
/Users/denisputnam/git/invoice-dapp>git push heroku master
remote: !   No such app as safe-escarpment-91432.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/safe-escarpment-91432.git/' not found
(base) iMac.fios-router.home:denisputnam
/Users/denisputnam/git/invoice-dapp>
```

Comment: Okay, so it would not let me do the "git push heroku master" it wanted the original app name.  I recreated the app name in the dashboard, and then ran 'heroku git:remote -a safe-escarpment-91432' to get it to add the app to my local git.  Is that what I needed to do with the new app?

Comment: If I change the app locally later, how do I get the git push to work?  That was the reason I deleted the original in the first place.